# Phonegap: is it possible to set and lock all camera parameters like resolution, focus, white-balance, color, depth?

Tags: cordova, photography, camera-calibration

Phonegap: I would like to know if it is possible to choose a set of parameters for the camera (Android, iOS, WP7), lock them and shoot many photos with those same parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Check out the cameraOptions..  Thats the max setting you can do using phonegap for now.